# Serilog MSSqlServer sink does not work when using ILogger interface

Tags: serilog

I am using Serilog MSSqlServer sink and have got it to write to database with
the built in static Log.Logger.  However, when I cast it to using ILogger logger
and use the interface instance logger to log, it no longer writes to database.
I read somewhere I would need to dispose this interface instance to write to database.
Is there an equivalent of Log.CloseAndFlush() for the interface instance?

The reason I am using ILogger and not Log.Logger is because I keep several ILogger instances at the same time writting to different tables.

Comment: you can do `Serilog.` `Log.CloseAndFlush()` if you assign the logger to `Log.Logger` - As you've learned, Disposing an arbitrary `ILogger` does not do the same thing (I believe the Serilog wiki covers this)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.